# Create dynamic section header in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to create custom section header with dynamic height. I have created a very simplified version of my app where I am displaying a square image as table section header. The image height is the same as the screen width. The tableView has to be dynamic because the image height changes with screen width. Even though the app works, I could not be able to get rid of the constraint warnings. It is a very simple app and I have no idea why it is throwing me constraint errors. It seems like the the 1:1 ratio on the image constraint is the root of the problem. I have attached the constraints of my xib file, code and output screenshot below.

[Xib Constraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6wDY.png)

[Simulator Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xFnj.png)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

    var xibRef: CustomHeaderView!
    var numberOfSection = 3

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myTableView.delegate = self
        myTableView.dataSource = self

        // Register Xib
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomHeaderView", bundle: nil)
        self.xibRef = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as? CustomHeaderView
        self.myTableView.registerNib(nib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "CustomHeaderView")
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel!.text = "section \(indexPath.section) row \(indexPath.row)"

        return cell
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return numberOfSection
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return view.frame.size.width
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("CustomHeaderView") as! CustomHeaderView

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: the estimated _height_ is actually the _width_? why could not it be `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` as well?

Comment: That does not work at all for me. I believe I needed to give the program an estimated value in order for it to process efficientely

Comment: did you experience any performance issues?